# Node.js passport error undefined is not a function when i put nothing in username and password field then submit

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This is my code.
when i login with email,password or wrong email  it's fine
but when i login with nothing in password, email field 
it show error 
   undefined is not a function
I fix it by write java script in front-end to put something in email,password field when user put nothing in that field
how i handle this error correctly

```js
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var crypto = require('crypto');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('user');

var flash = require('connect-flash');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 function(name,password,done){

  User.findOne({email:name},function(err, collection) {



   if(err) 
    return done(null,false);
   if(!collection)
    return done(null,false);
   var authenticated = checkPWD(collection,password);
   if(!authenticated)
    return done(null,false);
   return done(null,collection);


  });


  





/*
  if(username === 'admin' && password === 'lynda'){
   console.log("LOGIN AS "+username);
   return done(null,username);
  }

  return done(null,false);

  */
 }
 ));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
 done(null,user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
 done(null,user);
});

module.exports = passport;


function createSalt() {
 return crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
}

function hashPwd(salt, pwd) {
 var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt);
 return hmac.update(pwd).digest('hex');
}

function checkPWD(data,pwd){
 if(!data){ return false;};
 var salt = data.salt;
 var password = hashPwd(salt,pwd);
 if(!(password === data.hashed_pwd)){ return false;};

 return data;
 console.log(password);
 
 
 
}
```

Comment: Correct way is to provide client-side validation that will prevent submitting empty values. What's the sense of authenticating with empty login/password?

Comment: Please improve error checking - `if(err) return done(null,false);` - if there is error do not support it?

Comment: Thank you, i will provide client-side validation

Comment: i what i should do for improve error checking? @KrzysztofSafjanowski

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple check for email and password existing on the server side:

```
//...other code

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(name,password,done){

        if(!name || !password) return done(null,false, {message:'no name or password'});

        User.findOne({email:name},function(err, collection) {

        //...other code
```

But anyway you better do it on the client side as well.